# How to allow a user to click somewhere on your cmd window to select an item you have printed in it?

Tags: python, terminal

I'm designing a game and for this part of the game you must choose items off the table.

I want it so the player can click on an item and then I'll append it to their inventory. The only part which I have no idea on how to implement is the clicking on the picture and selecting the item.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w8tf.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.